# XSD: choice based on the condition of an element

Tags: xml, xsd, .net-4.0

I'm trying to come up with an XSD for this kind of XML:

```
<root>
  <valid>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>foo</b>
    <c>bar</c>
  </valid>
  <valid>
    <a>2</a>
    <c>bar</c>
    <d1>baz</d1>
  </valid>
  <valid>
    <a>3</a>
    <c>bar</c>
    <d2>baz-restricted</d2>
    <e>qux</e>
  </valid>
</root>
```

In all elements named `valid`, each child-element is mandatory.

I know I need to make the `xs:choice` conditional on the value of `a`, as the below XSD is ambiguous at the second occurence of `c`.

How can this be done in the XSD supported by .NET 4.x?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="valid">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="a" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element name="d1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element name="d2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                  <xs:element name="e" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(I know the XSD nested might be better off using custom types. If needed, I can make it custom, just let me know if it is in fact needed for a solution and I will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all elements named `valid`, each child-element is mandatory.

You cannot have same-named sibling elements be of different types in XSD 1.0.

You could use conditional type assignment in XSD 1.1 to do this, except...

> How can this be done in the XSD supported by .NET 4.x

...Microsoft does not support XSD 1.1.   You might consider using Saxon for .NET instead.

If you cannot switch to Saxon or another environment where XSD 1.1 is supported, either loosen your validation constraints or give the different versions of `valid` different names to reflect their different types.

Comment: Thanks. What if we could switch to Saxon for .NET? Would the XSD 1.1 solution become a mess?

Comment: No, Saxon would enable use of XSD 1.1, which is more expressive than XSD 1.0; see `xs:assertion` and conditional type assignment (`xs:alternative`).   However, if still possible, consider renaming the different `valid` elements and avoiding the need for the advanced XSD 1.1 facilities; this is not to avoid a "mess" but rather to follow a general XML naming best practice where different elements are named differently.

Comment: 'best practices' was the word I was looking for. Thanks. I've completely redesigned the XSD now as the party that delivered it was fine with a redesign whereas I thought the current design base was fixed.